# how do I take value from this $scope

Tags: angularjs

so I have this code in my chatting application, its for send message to the partner.

```
$scope.messages = {
            from      : $scope.datauser['data']['_id'],
            fromname  : $scope.datauser['data']['nama'],
            to        : $scope.tmpuserid,
            message   : $scope.tmp['sendmessage'],
            time      : moment()
        };
```

I want to add text-to-speech features in my application, the question is how I take the value from `$scope.messages` but just the *message* because if I just write `$scope.messages`, TTS will read all data from *from* until *time*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but if all you want to extract just the message from the messages $scope object you would use JS object dot notation e.g.

```
 var justMessage = $scope.messages.message;
 // justMessage = $scope.tmp['send message'];

 // OR parse an array 

var myPartnerMessages = [];

angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(msg, key) {
    this.push(msg.message);
}, myPartnerMessages);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want, but it would be something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages"> 
    <p>{{message.message}}</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: This answer is for iterating through an array of messages.

If it were just one messages object it would be:

```
<p>{{messages.message}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from `$scope` as follows:

View.html

```
 <div ng repeat="item in messages">
      <div>{{item.message}}</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just call the property as `$scope.messages.message`. Or since you already had it on another scope variable, you can call it as `$scope.tmp['sendmessage']`.

If you are trying to access from the HTML side, you would use it as this:

```
<p>{{messages.message}}</p>
```

Not exactly sure if this is what you need from reading your question, though.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a single object not an array if is an array you should use ng-repeat

On js end you can get it by

```
 $scope.messages.message
```

On html end you can get it by

```
 {{messages.message}}
```